# How I can get the vaule @sys-time in IBM Watson Assistant (Conversation)?

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

How I can get the value of time? 
This is my code but I can't see the time

```
{
  "context": {
    "time": "@sys-time"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Is $time"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: specify which platform or language you are using and show your code which is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [evaluation syntax](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects):

```
{
  "context": {
    "time": "<? @sys-time ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Is $time"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to also make sure, that in the dialog something with time is mentioned. `sys-time` does not have the system time, but user input related to time.

I have several [examples collected in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables).